# How to apply a tensor to a list of arguments

Tags: functions, symbolic, tensors

The problem I have is the following:

Let `C` be a list of coordinates, say, `C = {x1, x2, ..., xn}` and `T` be a tensor (possibly with symmetries) defined using the `Array` command (e.g., for a tensor with $3$ covariant components):

```
T = Array[ tt, { dim, dim, dim}]
```

where `dim = n`.
Now what I want is to declare that each and every component is a function of the coordinates.

Unfortunately, a command like:

```
T = Array[ tt[ x1, x2, ..., xn], { dim, dim, dim}]
```

does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look up `Function` or `Slot`. Define tt as `tt[x1[#1,#2,#3], x2[...], ...]&`

Answer (score 1):

Improving a bit on [@Sjoerd C. de Vries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/57/sjoerd-c-de-vries) comment, you use [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html) (`##`) to do the following:

```
c = {x1, x2};

T = Array[t[##] @@ c &, {2, 2}]
```

> ```
> {
>  {t[1, 1][x1, x2], t[1, 2][x1, x2]}, 
>  {t[2, 1][x1, x2], t[2, 2][x1, x2]}
> }
> ```

Taking partial derivatives w.r.t. to one of the coordinates (just to name an example) then works as expected:

```
D[T, x1]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]